# How to check whether an integer is present in the range in Scala?

Tags: scala, range

I have to check whether 2 is present in the range (2,5) .

How do I check that using Scala?

Comment: Do you know about the [online ScalaDocs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Range.html) pages? A very handy resource.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ranges in Scala are created using the methods `to` and `until`:

- `2 to 5` would give you inclusive-inclusive range with numbers `2,3,4,5`
- `2 until 5` would give you inclusive-exclusive range `2,3,4`

`Range`s provide the method `contains` to check for element membership, so

```
a to b contains x
```

would check whether `x` is in the range `a to b`, in your case, it would be

```
2 to 5 contains 2
```

if you wanted inclusive-inclusive, or

```
(2 + 1) until 5 contains 2
```

if you wanted exclusive-exclusive etc.

Comment: and now for the compulsive discussion about whether remembering the difference between `to` and `until` is more or _less_ readable than `x >= 2 && x <= 5`. I think it depends. ;-)

Comment: It's not so much about the readability, more about not duplicating `x`. The `x>= 2 && x <= 5` requires to bind `x` somewhere, otherwise the subexpression standing for the element would be evaluated twice.